# Win32: How to confirm exit with message box when Alt+F4 is pressed?

Tags: c, winapi

First, I cannot believe I am the first person to *ever* ask this question on SO.com.  More likely: The same question exists, but uses different terms.  If yes, please kindly close this question as a dupe and link to the original question.

Second:  I am writing C and using the Win32 API.  My goal is to display a message box to confirm application exit.

I know about three, different generic ways to exit a Win32 app.  (If there are more, please let me know.)

1. Press the `X` button in top right corner of main window which triggers Win32 event `WM_CLOSE`.
2. From the system menu (`Alt+Space`), select menu item `Close` which triggers Win32 event `WM_CLOSE`.
3. Press shortcut key `Alt+F4`

I am able to handle #1 and #2 correctly.  However, I am struggling to handle #3 correctly.

First, I tried `CreateAcceleratorTableW()` with `#define IDM_ACCEL_ALT_F4 203` and  `{.fVirt = (BYTE) (FALT | FVIRTKEY), .key = (WORD) VK_F4, .cmd = (WORD) IDM_ACCEL_ALT_F4}`.  However, `WM_COMMAND` is never triggered for this accelerator.  To be clear, using this same function, I am able to trap other shortcut keys, so I am confident my setup is correct.

Second, I monitored incoming Win32 events, but I never see: `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` plus `WPARAM wParam[115/0x73] (VK_F4)`.  Weirdly, I *do* see: `WM_SYSKEYUP` plus `WPARAM wParam[115/0x73] (VK_F4)`

Please advise.

Comment: 3) It's also WM_CLOSE

Comment: yes, it also use `WM_CLOSE`. also you can handle `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with `wParam == SC_CLOSE`

Comment: Did you read the [Closing the Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/closing-the-window) documentation on MSDN yet?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Doc:[Closing the Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/closing-the-window)

> **The user can close an application window by clicking the Close button,
> or by using a keyboard shortcut such as ALT+F4.** Any of these actions
> causes the window to receive a WM_CLOSE message. The WM_CLOSE message
> gives you an opportunity to prompt the user before closing the window.
> If you really do want to close the window, call the DestroyWindow
> function. Otherwise, simply return zero from the WM_CLOSE message, and
> the operating system will ignore the message and not destroy the
> window.

By default, pressing `ALT+F4` causes the window to receive WM_CLOSE message. ALT+F4 is the hotkey for closing a window. There is no need to create an accelerator table.